# toggle & animation in sencha touch

Tags: javascript, css, sencha-touch

[image]I am trying to toggle a image on button click which slides up and down. When i click on the expander button
below the top should be reduced.

In Jquery I use some thing like this to achieve the desired result.

```
$(function() {
    $("#legendExpand").toggle(function() {
        $("#legend").animate({'top': "370px"});
        $("div#legendExpand").html('<img src="img/expander-up.png" width="27" height="27"/>');        
    }, function() {
        $("#legend").animate({'top': "285px"});
        $("div#legendExpand").html('<img src="img/expander-down.png" width="27" height="27"/>');
    });
});
```

I am not sure how to achieve it using sencha touch.

I am able to detect the click event as shown below.

```
var legend = new Ext.Panel({
        id: 'legendPanel',
        html: '<div id="legend"><div id="legendExpand" class="legendExpand"><img class="expanderImage" src="resources/images/expander-down.png" width="27" height="27"/></div><div class="clear"></div><div id="layerOne"><div class="section">Availability:</div><div class="section" id="key"><div id="colorKey" class="dropUp"><div class="top"><div class="colorLink">Standard Colors</div><div class="clear"></div><div class="divider"></div><div class="colorLink">High Contrast</div><div class="clear"></div><div class="divider"></div><div class="colorLink">Color Blind (Red/Green)</div><div class="clear"></div><div class="divider"></div><div class="colorLink">Color Blind (Blue/Yellow)</div><div class="clear"></div><div class="divider"></div></div><!-- END top --><div class="bottom"><div class="standardColors"><img src="resources/images/standardColors.png" width="129" height="29" /></div><div class="clear"></div></div><!-- END bottom --></div><!-- END colorKey --><!--<div id="changeColorsLink"><a href="#"><strong>Change Colors</strong></a></div> END changeColorsLink --></div><!-- END section --><div class="clear"></div><div class="dotted"></div><div id="layerTwo"><ul class="legend"><li>Key:</li><li><img src="resources/images/legend_P.png" width="22" height="34" /></li><li>Parking<br />Facilities</li><li><img src="resources/images/legend_PR.png" width="33" height="34"/></li><li>Park &amp; Ride<br />Facility</li><li><img src="resources/images/legend_SP.png" width="27" height="34" /></li><li>Street<br />Parking</li></ul></div><div class="clear"></div></div><!-- END layerOne --></div>',
        listeners: {
            'afterrender': function () {
                Ext.getCmp('legendPanel').getEl().on('click', function (e, t) {
                    e.stopEvent();


            }, null, { delegate: 'img.expanderImage' });
        }
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`this.hide(); this.destroy(); this.doLayout();`

The above will hide the legend component.  You can then update the html with the correct expander image (you'll want to do this before the doLayout since this forces a redraw).

You can also refer to the legendPanel as `this`, rather than use Ext.getCmp().